# How to Update a MySQL DATETIME to NOW()? (Error 1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am encountering the MySQL `error 1064` trying to update the `datetime` column `exit`.

```
UPDATE history SET
exit = NOW()
WHERE city = 'Paris'
```

I don't understand why it occurs.

Comment: Can you share the full text of the error please?

Comment: Any time you're going to ask about an error on SO, take it for granted that we need to see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` is a reserved word in MySQL (see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) for reference).

I recommend that you rename the column in your table to avoid such future inconveniences. If you cannot, however, you could escape the column name by surrounding it with backticks:

```sql
UPDATE history 
SET    `exit` = NOW()
-- Here^----^
WHERE  city = 'Paris'
```